# Text To Speech: SpeechSynthesis Data Installer

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am attempting to work with Text to Speech, and I am having an issue with even testing out the application I have created. I have the following code snippet in my code that checks to see if you have the tools necessary for Text to Speech to work, if not it attempts to install them.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == checkData && requestCode == 
            TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        m_TTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the attempt to install is a redirect to google Play where it pulls up the [SpeechSynthesis Data Installer](http://appcrawlr.com/android/speechsynthesis-data-installer). The conflict I am having is that as soon that you install this application it uninstalls. I have attempted many times, and the comments indicate that this is a common issue. My question is, do I have to use this specific speechsynthesis data installer? Are there others that work better? What can I do as a work around? I believe that the application will work, I just need to be able to test it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an answer. Apparently this is not something the developer can control. The user has to install some sort of SpeechSynthesis program, it can be any program before running your text to speech application. If this is done, or  if the phone already has this feature pre-installed (most ICS phones do) then the application will not redirect to google play store and will work fine. SpeechSynthesis Data Installer is the worse of all the speechsythesis programs, some alternatives like google's translate works better.